# How to save multiple records from List view to the database in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I am stucked coding from saving my attachments from listView to my database. I'd like to save the attached filename, description, uploadedBy, and dateUploaded but for some reasons, I can't save it successfully. Are my codes from my saving process correct?

```
String ReportCode = tv_Code.getText().toString();
String attachedFile = textViewTitle.getText().toString();
String attachedDescription = txt_Desc.getText().toString();
String attachedURI = tv_Uri.getText().toString();
String attachedUploadedBy = tv_CreatedBy.getText().toString();
String attachedDateUploaded = tv_DateCreated.getText().toString();

//SAVE All Attachment
databaseHandler.SaveAttach(new Cons_Attach (ReportCode, attachedFile, attachedURI, attachedDescription, attachedUploadedBy, attachedDateUploaded));                                     

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ReportCode + "\n" + attachedFile + "\n" + attachedURI + "\n" + attachedDescription 
                        + "\n" + attachedUploadedBy + "\n" + attachedDateUploaded, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Populating the ListView

```
//Method in populating to List View
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View rowView = null;
        try{
            rowView = inflater.inflate(resource, null, true);
            textViewTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(to[0]);
            txt_Desc = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(to[1]);
            tv_CreatedBy = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(to[2]);
            tv_DateCreated= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(to[3]);
            final TextView tv_Action = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(to[4]);
            final TextView tv_rowId = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(to[5]);
            tv_Uri = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(to[6]);

            final String FileKey = from[0];
            String DescKey = from[1];
            String UploadedByKey = from[2];
            String DateUploadKey = from[3];
            String ActionKey = from[4];
            final String idKey = from[5];
            String FileUri = from[6];

            final String FileName = unfilteredValues.get(position).get(FileKey).toString();
            String Desc = unfilteredValues.get(position).get(DescKey).toString();
            String UploadedBy = unfilteredValues.get(position).get(UploadedByKey).toString();
            String DateUpload = unfilteredValues.get(position).get(DateUploadKey).toString();
            String Action = unfilteredValues.get(position).get(ActionKey).toString();
            String AttachId = unfilteredValues.get(position).get(idKey).toString();
            String FileNameUri = unfilteredValues.get(position).get(FileUri).toString();

            textViewTitle.setText(FileName);
            txt_Desc.setText(Desc);
            tv_CreatedBy.setText(UploadedBy);
            tv_DateCreated.setText(DateUpload);
            tv_Action.setText(Action);
            tv_rowId.setText(AttachId);
            tv_Uri.setText(FileNameUri);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (OutOfMemoryError E){
            E.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rowView;
```

DatabaseHandler.java

```
public void SaveAttach(Cons_Attach save){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Constants.REPORT_CODE, save.getReportCode()); // Save Report Code
    values.put(Constants.ATTACH_FILENAME, save.getFile()); // Save File
    values.put(Constants.ATTACH_FILELOCATION, save.getURI()); // Save URI
    values.put(Constants.ATTACH_DESCRIPTION, save.getDescription()); // Save Description
    values.put(Constants.ATTACH_CREATEDBY, save.getUploadedBy()); // Save UploadedBy
    values.put(Constants.ATTACH_DATECREATED, save.getDateUploaded()); // Save Date Upload

    db.insert(Constants.TABLE_ATTACH, null, values);
    db.close(); 
}
```

Comment: are you getting any error or crash? then post the stack trace here also

Comment: i don't get any error from this code. I can't get and can't save the records from the listView

Comment: Ok then can you please post your database method for saving the data from list view to db

Comment: Please see the updated codes above

Comment: Maybe your using an in memory sqlite database?

Comment: Actually I am using external database

Comment: what do you mean by external database? the database in assets folder.?

Comment: Yes it is. I really don't have any idea regarding this